# execCommand doesn't fire when called from keydown event in Windows Store apps

Tags: windows, html, windows-store-apps, onkeydown

I'm writing a windows store app (HTML) that includes some simple rich-text editing. I can apply bold to the currently selected using a button which fires `document.execCommand("bold",false,null);`

However when I bind this to a keydown event like CTRL+B, nothing happens. Here's my keydown code.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", catchShortCuts, false);

function catchShortCuts(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        if (e.keyCode == 66) // b
            document.execCommand('bold', true, null);
        }
    }
}
```

I know my keydown code works fine because if I replace the `document.execCommand` with another line of code it fires just fine when I press CTRL+B. It seems like execCommand has a problem with the keydown event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that it works fine if you use **keypress** instead of **keydown**. Just in case anyone else has the same issue, that's a workaround. Still not sure why onkeydown doesn't work though.

Working code:

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", catchShortCuts, false);

function catchShortCuts(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        if (e.keyCode == 66) // b
            document.execCommand('bold', true, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: even more strange is that the keypress captures the CTRL .

Comment: why is that strange? keydown does that too

Comment: Making this issue go from "strange" to "limiting", is that the [ESC key does not register in onkeypressed()](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2264#issuecomment-122993892).  Hence you can't call `document.execCommand()` in response to escape.

Comment: 5 years on it occurs to me that this might have been an issue when debugging, as Visual Studio uses CTRL-B to select elements in the DOMExplorer